# Steel vintage bike restoration and modification, troubleshooting help

Tags: crankset, compatibility, vintage, restoration

I acquired a vintage 10 speed Healing Commuter made in New Zealand, rode it everyday and treated it pretty poorly. No regular maintenance, chained it on the street come rain or shine. Having grown fond of it I decided I would do a complete over haul.

Fast forward 6 months, it’s a new colour and all the mech is working well... independently.

The bike has all its original parts except:

- The derailleur now a Shimano Tourney 6 speed SIS
- Both wheels now Shimano specialised pro mondo with a 6 speed cassette and
- A new chain now a 7mm SRAM chain with a quicklink.

The crankset is a Shimano Front Freewheel System - from what I can tell, the FFS was pretty low end and a solution in search of a problem, to quote Sheldon.

Sadly my first ride was lack-luster thanks to a knock. When pedaling with gusto, something in the crank system is slipping so the rider experiences the pedal engaging normally followed by no opposite force from the pedal followed by the pedal engaging normally again. This occurs rhythmically and on both sides, when left foot is leading then right then left etc.

I’m wondering if it’s something to do with the crankset being a freewheel system plus the free hub system in the considerably newer wheels?

Maybe it’s an error I made in the rebuild of the crank?

Any crank troubleshooting tips would be much appreciated.

Ta

[image: The Bike, have re-routed the cabling along the toptube[![][1]][1]]
[image: close up of the Shimano Front Freewheel System]

Comment: Did you replace the chain too?

Comment: Yes I did, with a 7mm SRAM chain with a quicklink.

Comment: So you cleaned and refitted the original front chainring and cranks?  Or is the "Shimano Front Freewheel System" something you added?  From memory that was a way of allowing the chainrings to rotate forward with the crank arms stationary.  I've never seen one in the wild, a photo might help.    This sounds fixable, so do persevere!

Comment: Did you replace the cassette with a new one?  Its possible the new chain is slipping on an old worn cassette.   If the cassette has individual cogs you might get away with flipping each cog, but the splines don't quite line up and some filing is needed.   Does it happen in all gears?    Basically need to identify what is slipping.

Comment: Hi Criggie, the Shimano Front Freewheel System is original and I removed and cleaned it. The chain rings are spot welded, so other than removing the pedal arms, lock rings and cage bearings, the unit is sealed. The cassette is new to the freehub but not a new item. All components seem right as rain when the bike is in the stand, no chain slipping at the cassette in any gear, no cluncking at the BB - My LBS even looked it over and said it was fine (this was before I went out on my first ride and noticed the problem). Will add some pics to the OP.

Comment: Sounds to me like the chain is slipping, possibly because it's too long.  (Though it doesn't appear to be to long in the picture.)

Comment: Unrelated - why did you route the back brake cable like that ?  Those three clips should have been around the top tube, giving you a shorter total run with less-aggressive bends.  Second, what's up with the bartape wrap pattern?  I've never seen one like that before.

Comment: Back to your problem - Do you value the front freewheel?   I'd suggest fitting up a boring bottom bracket cartridge, and pairing it with a regular double crank.  Most bike nutters have something adequate in their spares pile (If you were in Chch I'd loan you parts for a test fit-up)  Or hit up Trademe for a double crankset and cartridge.  Being a NZ Healing, it will 99% likely be a standard English threadded 68mm BB.

Comment: With the bike standing still can you put enough pressure on the pedals to replicate the slip? If so you will either see the pedals move and the chain not move = slipping at the chain ring, or you will see pedals move and chain move = slipping at the freewheel.

Comment: @DavidD good idea, but even on bikes with known chain jump/slip probs I've never been able to replicate that.  My best method for identifying wear is visually.

Comment: @Criggie, I was testing different routes when I took the photo, have since re-routed along the top tube. The bar tape was my attempt at bullwhip braided leather bar wraps from Walnut Studio. I didn’t have the cash for the pre-made ones but had access to cheap leather scraps!

Comment: I’m not married to the FFS but I do like the classic look it gives the bike. Luckily I have access to heaps of parts thanks to being a volunteer at the local community bike repair shop so can test with a different BB. I went into my LBS today and described the problem to a mechanic who suggested it could be the free hub slipping. will give DavidD’s suggestion a go on a bit and report back.

Comment: @Criggie I suspect that the front freewheel is slipping. If so it should be reproducible standing still. Chain slip is difficult to reproduce.

Comment: Hi all, the mystery continues. Not reproducible standing still.

Comment: Unrelated: I’m not sure if it’s a problem to clamp the bike stand on the top tube but  around the seat post or seat tube in the seat post area would be much safer.

Comment: @Michael good thinking, but this is a steel bike from the 80s.  It'll be fine.  Would be a different matter if it were carbon fibre.

Answer (score 2):

I had a Schwinn World Tourist and those had the freewheel system, too. It might... *might* be because you have two freewheels. The bikes that had those, had fixed gears on the wheel, since it was the crank that coasted. And yes, the whole point of the system was so you could change gears by coasting.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally gotten to the bottom of the bottom bracket problem.

The thread inside the spindle was worn and the NDS crank arm was moving independently from the DS crank arm.

Have replaced the FFS with a cup and cone BB with a retro chain guard, which is now engaging nicely.

Still have, what I now know is chain slip, just got to sus out whether its the chainrings or the free hub.

Thanks for all your troubleshooting.

[image: BB with retro chainguard]